# Select multiple cells depending on value of If InStr, copy and paste to new sheet in the next row then increment down to the next occurence

Tags: excel, vba

I want to select these sheet7 cells: `A1,A3:J3,A4,A5,A7,D7,A8,D8`.

If A1 has "API" string and J1 has a specific string copy the range of cells and paste to sheet8 in 1st empty row.

Else I want to test `A1` for "API" in string and copy `A1,A3:J3,A4,A5,A7,D7` and paste to sheet8 in 1st empty row.

Then I want to test the next row for the same as above until I reach the next "API" and increment the copy cells and paste them to sheet8 in next empty row.

I have searched far and wide and cannot find how to increment the `Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("A1,A3:J3,A4,A5,A7,D7,A8,D8")`. I keep getting the same range copied to the next line in Sheet8. I've tried R1C1 format and using variables with `&` and still get errors.

I've also included my code and the data I'm running it on.
Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm just beginning in VBA.
My data looks like this:

```
A   B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
```

1 A1str .........................J1str
2 string in each cell but don't need
3 string in each cell need all
4 A4str
5 A5str
6 string in 1st 4 cells but don't need
7 A7str       D7str in 1st 4 cells need A & D
8 A8str and D8str needed if J1 has strg

Need each of the above 17 cells in 1st available row on sheet8

Why do i get a Run-time error '1004' with the following code:

```
    i = 1  
    k = i + 6   
    Set copyRange = Worksheets("Sheet7").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(k, 10))
```

Seems to me this is setting a range from A1:J7

```
Option Explicit

Sub Find_APIandSideTrack2()

    Dim copyRange As Range, pasteRange As Range, mycel As Range, myRange As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim Row As Variant, Cell As Variant
    Dim erow As Integer, ecolumn As Integer
       
    lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set myRange = Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("A1", "A" & lastrow)
    Debug.Print myRange.Address
    
    For Each Row In myRange
        
        If InStr(1, Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("A1").Value, "API", 1) <> 0 And InStr(1, Worksheets("Sheet7") _
            .Range("J1").Value, "   |    SideTrack Cnt  - 2", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
            i = 0
            
            Set copyRange = Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("A1,A3:J3,A4,A5,A7,D7,A8,D8")
            erow = Worksheets("Sheet8").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
            Set pasteRange = Worksheets("Sheet8").Range("A1" & erow)
            
            For Each Cell In copyRange
                Cell.Copy
                ecolumn = Sheet8.Cells(erow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, i).Column
                pasteRange.Cells(1, ecolumn).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                i = 1
                
            Next
        
        ElseIf InStr(1, Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("A1").Value, "API", 1) <> 0 Then
            i = 0
            Set copyRange = Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("A1,A3:J3,A4,A5,A7,D7")
            erow = Worksheets("Sheet8").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
            Set pasteRange = Worksheets("Sheet8").Range("A" & erow)
            
            For Each Cell In copyRange
                Cell.Copy
                ecolumn = Sheet8.Cells(erow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, i).Column
                pasteRange.Cells(1, ecolumn).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            i = 1
            
            Next
        Else
            
        End If
        
    Next Row
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Think I've figured out my own question so I'm posting the answer here with comments where I discovered what would and wouldn't work. The answer is you can't create a range of non adjacent cells and then increment through the same relevant cells in a loop. You have to set the range to be equal to the entire range of data even with blanks and cells that have no data.
Would appreciate if someone could critique as a way to improve and make faster.
Thanks.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Find_APIandST_Print_All()

    Dim CopyRange As Range, pasteRange As Range, Cell As Range, rng As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, lastrow As Long
    Dim erow   As Integer, ecol As Integer
    Dim shSource As Worksheet 'set Worksheets as variables which makes code easier to read
    Dim shDest As Worksheet

    Set shSource = Worksheets("Sheet7")
    Set shDest = Worksheets("Sheet8")
```

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

```
lastrow = shSource.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = shSource.Range("A1", "A" & lastrow) 'set the rng to loop through

    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count 'set up the loop from shSource
        
        If InStr(1, shSource.Range("A" & i).Value, "API", 1) <> 0 And _
        InStr(1, shSource.Range("J" & i).Value, "SideTrack", 1) <> 0 Then
            
            j = 0
            k = i + 7
            
            Set CopyRange = shSource.Range(shSource.Cells(i, 1), shSource.Cells(k, 10)) 

           'This was the sticking point as couldn't copy and iterate through the loop  
           'with the individual cells from the original question.
           'Set copyRange = Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("A1,A3:J3,A4,A5,A7,D7,A8,D8")

            CopyRange.Copy
            erow = shDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
            Set pasteRange = shDest.Range("A" & erow)
            
            For Each Cell In CopyRange
                Cell.Copy
                ecol = shDest.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, j).Column
                pasteRange.Cells(1, ecol).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                j = j + 1
                
            Next
            
        Else
            If InStr(1, shSource.Range("A" & i).Value, "API", 1) <> 0 Then
                j = 0
                k = i + 6
            Set CopyRange = shSource.Range(shSource.Cells(i, 1), shSource.Cells(k, 10))
           'This was the sticking point as couldn't copy and iterate through the loop  
           'with the individual cells from the original question.
           'Set copyRange = Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("A1,A3:J3,A4,A5,A7,D7")

            CopyRange.Copy
            erow = shDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
            Set pasteRange = shDest.Range("A" & erow)
            
            For Each Cell In CopyRange
                Cell.Copy
                ecol = shDest.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, j).Column
                pasteRange.Cells(1, ecol).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                j = j + 1
                
            Next
            End If
        End If
        
    Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Complete"

End Sub
```